# How to number chapters as "x.0"

Tags: sectioning, numbering

The default numbering for chapters is this:

```
1 Chapter
1.1 Section
```

What I **want** is this:

```
1.0 Chapter
1.1 Section
```

However, if I add the zero to `\thechapter`, what I *get* is this:

```
1.0 Chapter
1.0.1 Section
```

How do I get that ".0" appended to the chapter header?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Define `\thesection` without using `\thechapter`, such as

```
\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.0}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
```

Comment: ...and the numbering of `\subsection` etc. picks up that "definition without `\thechapter`" from `\thesection`... sweet. Why didn't *I* see this? :-D

Answer (score 1):

**Expanding on @Stefan's answer for the `article` document class**

When you are using the `book` document class, you have chapters, but not when using `article`. For that use case, you redefine `\thesection` as above, without redefining `\thechapter`, and then follow that with redefining `\thesubsection` instead. That gives you the same result as sought in the OP without having to use the `book` document class:

```
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
```