# Solid black boxes in multiline chaper titles

Tags: sectioning, formatting

Me again... very close to the layout I'm looking for already, but not *quite* there yet. ;-)

For chapter headers, I am trying to get this look for chapter headings:

[image: I.C.E.'s Rolemaster]

I.e.,

- `\thechapter` centered,
- with a solid black box (the same height as the numbers) to the left and to the right, spanning the width of the text area.
- The name of the chapter on the next line, also centered, without the boxes.

I got the "Chapter" string removed, I got the ".0" appended to the chapter number (thanks to [Stefan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/how-to-number-chapters-as-x-0) for helping with that one), and contentet myself with writing `\chapter{MYCHAPTER}` instead of trying to get LaTeX doing the uppercasing for me. I get "*1.0 MYCHAPTER*" written for a chapter header - so far so good.

But now I am stuck. I read and googled, and found plenty of examples using `\@startsection` for adding boxes around headers, lines above and lines below and backdrops behind them, getting increasingly more complex and daunting - but couldn't figure out how to do those black boxes to the left and the right of the chapter numbers.

Help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the `titlesec` package I can get you some of the way there:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\hrulefill\thechapter.0\hrulefill}{20pt}{\Huge\center}
```

I've basically copied the standard definition, but changed the third mandatory argument to `\hrulefill\thechapter.0\hrulefill`. What `\hrulefill` does is fill the available horizontal space with a rule.

With a `\rule` you could create your thick rules as follows: `\rule{10em}{1ex}` which would give a rule `10em` long and `1ex` thick. I don't know how to get a "thick" `\hrulefill` though.

I hope this goes some way towards solving your problem.

Comment: See [this answer to another question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17124/what-is-the-rule-equivalent-for-hrule/17130#17130) for making a "thick" `\hrulefill`.

Comment: You could as well redefine `\thechapter`: `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.0}`.

Comment: @Raphink: Already did so.

Answer (score 3):

Seamus and You got me on the right track. This is a combination of their hints:

```
% Ignore-The-Height (ith), used to avoid additional vspace
% e.g. with umlauts. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29911.
\newcommand{\ith}[1]
    {\leavevmode\smash{\uppercase{#1}}}

% Variable-width rulers, default width 14pt
\newcommand*\varhrulefill[1][14pt]
    {\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height#1\hfill\kern0pt}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
    {\varhrulefill\enskip\thechapter\enskip\varhrulefill}
    {12pt}
    {\center\ith}
```

- I changed the default height of `\varhrulefill` from You's link to 14pt as that is my desired default size;
- I added a `\enskip` to push the boxes a bit away from the chapter numbers;
- I added an `\uppercase` to the *after* command so I actually *don't* have to write the chapter title in uppercase myself.
- *I came back two months later to include [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29911) improvement and the general evolution of the solution to this answer.*

The result is pretty much *exactly* what I were looking for:

[image]

Thanks, guys. You are awesome.

Comment: I give the "correct answer" to Seamus because he got me on the right track.