# titlesec: Vertical space that I don't want

Tags: spacing, sectioning, titlesec

Again me, still trying to emulate a very specific layout...

I used the `titlesec` package to define chapter and section titles, and am very pleased with the outcome... except of some ponts' worth of vertical space that keep showing up in places where I don't want them. Perhaps you guys can help me out here.

The almost-M-WE is below... all `pt` values in the source have been figured out from the original with a ruler, I left them in because they are as good as any. Never mind the faulty subsection numbering, that's been taken care of in the "real" document.

This code *almost* works. I have two problems with it though:

- If the chapter title contains an Umlaut (Ä, Ö, Ü), additional vertical whitespace gets added between the bars and the title. This isn't exactly a showstopper as I could rename the chapters in a way so they don't contain Umlauts, but I would like to know why this happens and if there is a way to avoid it.
- I used a baseline smaller than the fontsize in the `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` formats to emulate the very compact layout of the original book. However, this setting seems to work *only between the second and third line* of a long title - there is extra vertical whitespace *between the first and second line*, which does not get reduced even if I set a yet smaller baseline. If it were the other way around, I could easily work around having three-line titles, but I cannot avoid having two-line titles, and would like to know how to reduce that vspace.

Thanks in advance, you guys have been a great help already in my quest into the LaTeX world!

```
\documentclass[open=any,twocolumn]{scrbook}

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{11pt}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{14pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{11pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{5pt}{0pt}

% scaleable chapter bars, credit to Gonzalo Medina, tex.sx #17124
\newcommand*\varhrulefill[1][17pt]
{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height#1\hfill\kern0pt}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}.0}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\fontsize{25pt}{0pt}\bfseries\sffamily}
    {\varhrulefill\enskip\thechapter\enskip\varhrulefill}
    {-4pt}
    {\center\MakeUppercase}

\newcommand{\trailthesubsection}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1} (\thesubsection)}
\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalfont\fontsize{15pt}{14pt}\bfseries\sffamily}
    {}
    {0pt}
    {\filcenter\trailthesubsection}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
    {\normalfont\fontsize{12pt}{11pt}\bfseries\scshape}
    {}
    {0pt}
    {\filcenter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Functional}      % This one looks as it should

\chapter{Düsfunctional}   % The Umlaut triggers extra vspace

% Notice the extra, non-reducable whitespace after the first line break
\subsection{My Long Subsection Title breaking the line twice}
\subsubsection{My Very Long Subsubsection Title actually breaking the line twice}

\end{document}
```

A pasted-together output sample. Red lines point out the offending vspace.

[image: Red lines point out the offending vspace.]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Question 1: You have to "hide" the height of the title

```
\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}.0}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\fontsize{25pt}{0pt}\bfseries\sffamily}
    {\varhrulefill\enskip\thechapter\enskip\varhrulefill}
    {12pt} % <--- modify this for lowering the title
    {\center\ignoretitleheight}
\newcommand{\ignoretitleheight}[1]{\leavevmode\smash{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
```

Question 2: You have to avoid inserting the `\lineskip` when two lines are "too near" to each other

```
\newcommand{\trailthesubsection}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1} (\thesubsection)}
\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalfont\fontsize{15pt}{14pt}\bfseries\sffamily\lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen}
    {}
    {0pt}
    {\filcenter\trailthesubsection}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
    {\normalfont\fontsize{12pt}{11pt}\bfseries\scshape\lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen}
    {}
    {0pt}
    {\filcenter}
```

However the spacing won't be uniform if some character is higher than the stated baseline skip (an accented uppercase letter, for example).

Comment: Answer 1 worked like a charm. As for Answer 2... now that you've set me on the right track, any reason why I shouldn't just `\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}`? It looks good enough in the context of the MWE, and my book won't have much (if any) math or figures in it...? (On second thought, wouldn't `\squash`ing the titles help with the accented uppercase letters here, too?)

Comment: Setting `\lineskiplimit` to `-\maxdimen` will even avoid putting `\lineskip` glue. And, contrary to what I said, will give uniform spacing, but higher characters will possibly overlap with the line above. `\smash` makes a hbox, so no line break is possible.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation, I really was wondering. ;-)

Comment: One more question, if you don't mind... how come TeX figured that `\lineskip` is necessary, *but only in the first line break*?

Comment: I suspect that **titlesec** puts a strut at the beginning of the title.