# Inconsistent line spacing in beamer frametitle due to capital German umlauts

Tags: beamer, line-spacing

I have the following problem:

Suppose I have a frametitle which takes two lines. Depending on whether the second line contains a character which uses the very upper part of the line like an 'Ü' (German umlaut), the space between the two lines differs.

Switching slides, the second line of the title may jump up and down (which is unwanted :-)).

As far as I have tested, this problem only occurs in the frame title and not for the body. I also found a post, describing a similar problem for chapter titles, but I wasn't able to figure out how to do this with beamer:
[titlesec: Vertical space that I don't want](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29911/titlesec-vertical-space-that-i-dont-want)

Any idea is very welcome!

Edit:
Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{This is a very long frame title. There is no capital umlaut, so the spacing is ok.}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{This is another very long frame title. The following capital umlaut Ü changes the spacing.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I think you can add `\strut` to every second line without Ü.

Comment: Thank you for the nice welcome, Jubobs! I added an MWE to the post. Can I also upload the corresponding pdf files? Thank you also, Ignasi. I don't exactly understand your suggestion...I don't manually set up the lines, the line break is done by LaTeX.

Comment: Your Umlaut is indeed affecting the local interline spacing. Why don't you increase it globally to avoid that, using the `setspace` package? For instance, try inserting `\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}` in your preamble. You can fine-tune the value passed to `\setstretch` to your liking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\linespread{1.1}\Large}
```

so the frame title lines will be spread apart a bit more, leaving room for accented uppercase letters.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem. The `\setstretch{1.5}` did the job as well, but it also changed the body spacing which was not intended.