# Chapter without pagebreak? (In twocolumn document.)

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, chapters, two-column

I've googled, and I read a lot about how not having a pagebreak before a new `chapter` is bad style. I've read about how one could use sections instead. I've read about how *changing* whether a chapter begins on a new page or not within a document is even worse, from a style standpoint.

However, if I still **have** to do it somehow, typographic style be damned, *and I have to do it in a `twocolumn` document*...

Background: I am translating a set of gaming rulebooks into a single `scrbook`, with each original rulebook represented by a `part` in my `scrbook`. Layout of the rulebooks is relatively uniform, with [fancy chapter headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25296/solid-black-boxes-in-multiline-chaper-titles) beginning on a new page each.

The exception to this is the first rulebook / `part`, which has very short chapters, sometimes several on a single page, but following the same numbering scheme as the more elaborate chapters in the other rulebooks / `part`s.

I could typeset that first book seperately, using sections instead of chapters, and `include` the resulting PDF. That way, I would lose the common TOC / LOT / index, which would be unfortunate.

I could wing it by redefining header formats for the first part, to make sections "look" like chapters and subsections look like sections and subsubsections... and so on. Pretty heavy-handed.

**Edit:** The solution in [Start new chapter on same page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/start-new-chapter-on-same-page) (using `etoolbox` to patch the `clearpage` / `cleardoublepage` out of the definition of `\chapter`) does not work for a `twocolumn` document, yielding "Float(s) lost" errors. (I hadn't mentioned the `twocolumn` detail before as I did not think it would make a difference.) User *lockstep* asked for a seperate question; instead, I vote for re-opening this (edited) one.

---

**tl;dr:**

**Is there a way to tell LaTeX not to put a pagebreak for `\chapter` *in a `twocolumn` document*?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As switching between `twocolumn` and `onecolumn` causes a page break, one may use the [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package and its `multicols` environment instead. (The environment's optional argument is used for introductory one-column material.) In the following example, I use the `twocolumn` class option to achieve smaller margins, then temporarily switch two `\onecolumn` at the start of the document. Page breaks before chapters are removed by disabling `\clearpage` inside a group.

Note: The vertical space before chapter 1 (typeset with `multicols`) is actually larger than the space before chapter 3 (typeset with `\twocolumn`). The larger space is caused by LaTeX bug 3126 (`\twocolumn` interfering with `\topskip`); for consistent spacing, use `multicols` environments for every chapter of your document. EDIT: Even better, use Frank Mittelbachs [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39716/510) to [Is it possible to define a `multicols{2}` preamble switch that works for \chapter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39713/is-it-possible-to-define-a-multicols2-preamble-switch-that-works-for-chapte)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}

\newcommand*{\sometext}{Hello, here is some text without a meaning. This
    text should show, how a printed text will look like at this place.
    If you read this text, you will get no information.}

\begin{document}

\onecolumn

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax

\begin{multicols}{2}[%
  \chapter{First (and some text to fill the line)}%
]

\sometext

\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{2}[%
  \chapter{Second (and some text to fill the line)}%
]

\sometext

\end{multicols}

\endgroup

\twocolumn

\chapter{Third (and some text to fill the line)}

\sometext

\chapter{Fourth (and some text to fill the line)}

\sometext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: *Sigh*... Yes, this solves the immediate problem. *And* gives me the next one: multicols and tables... :-P Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

`onecolumn` inserts page break, redefine it!

```
\def\onecolumn{%
%  \clearpage
  \global\columnwidth\textwidth
  \global\hsize\columnwidth
  \global\linewidth\columnwidth
  \global\@twocolumnfalse
  \col@number \@ne
  \@floatplacement}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who only want the chapter without pagebreak. Simply add

```
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{}
\renewcommand{\clearpage}{}
```

At the beginning of the `\chapter{}`

Comment: Part of lockstep's answer, but since he puts a `\begingroup` in front of his `\let\clearpage\relax` and an `\endgroup` behind what it is supposed to affect, his solution doesn't clear those commands for the remaining document -- only for where they are needed to be cleared.