# Is it possible to define a `multicols{2}` preamble switch that works for \chapter?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, multicol, preamble

With standard LaTeX, issuing `\twocolumn` in the preambe causes the document to be typeset in two columns -- except that `\chapter` will produce separate one-column chapter headings.

```
\documentclass{book}

\twocolumn% Note: this doesn't change page margins

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

If one wants balanced columns at the end of last (chapter) pages, one may use the [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package and its `multicols` environment. However, simply enclosing the whole document body in `\begin{multicols}{2}` ... `\end{multicols}` won't do because a) `\chapter` headings become part of the first column and b) the last pages of any but the last chapter won't feature balanced columns. Instead, one has to use separate `multicols` environments for every chapter and to issue `\chapter` within the optional argument of `multicols`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\chapter{First}

\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{Second}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{2}[\chapter{Third}]
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is it possible to define a `multicols{2}` switch similar to `\twocolumn` that may be issued in the document preamble and that produces separate one-column `\chapter` headings?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to issue a `\clearpage` command at the end of each chapter (while using the `multicols` environment)?

Comment: A partial solution that does away with multiple `multicols` environments will gain an upvote (though not necessarily be accepted).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A simple solution would look somewhat like this:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{multicol}

\makeatletter
\def\closeopenmulticols{%
% test if current env is "multicols" if so close it
   \def\@tempa{multicols}%
   \ifx\@tempa\@currenvir
      \end{multicols}%
  \fi 
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\Mychapter[1]{%
 \closeopenmulticols
% start new multicols with chapter
  \begin{multicols}{2}[\chapter{#1}]}


% close last open multicols
\AtEndDocument{\closeopenmulticols}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\Mychapter{First}    
\lipsum[1-2]

\Mychapter{Second}    
\lipsum[1-2]    
\end{document}
```

Obvious improvements would be to redefine `\chapter` to work like `\Mychapter` but with the optional arguments of the standard heading commands - exercise for the reader ;-) ... happy new year (soon).

### Update

Here is a slightly more elaborate solution that actually implements the switch that was asked for (or rather two switches `\startchaptercols[<colno>]` and `\stopchaptercols`) that change the behavior on the next `\chapter` command).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{multicol}

\makeatletter
\def\closeopenmulticols{%
% test if current env is "multicols" if so close it
   \def\@tempa{multicols}%
   \ifx\@tempa\@currenvir
      \end{multicols}%
  \fi }
\makeatother

\let\origchapter\chapter

%parse optional args if present and save them
\def\mychapter#1#{\gdef\buildmychapter{\origchapter#1}\mychapteri}
% parse mandatory arg and do the work
\def\mychapteri#1{\closeopenmulticols
% start new multicols with chapter
  \begin{multicols}{\chaptercols}[\buildmychapter{#1}]}

\newcommand\startchaptercols[1][2]{\gdef\chaptercols{#1}\global\let\chapter\mychapter}
\def\stopchaptercols{\gdef\chapter{\closeopenmulticols\origchapter}}

% close last open multicols
\AtEndDocument{\closeopenmulticols}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\startchaptercols    % start next chapter with two columns
\tableofcontents
\startchaptercols[3]    % start next chapter with three columns

\chapter{First}
\section{foo} \lipsum[1-2]
\startchaptercols    % start next chapter with two columns (no immediate change)
\section{foo} \lipsum[1-2]

\chapter[Running second]{Second}
\lipsum[1-2] \section{foo} \lipsum[1-2]
\stopchaptercols    % stop at next chapter (if any)
\section{foo} \lipsum[1-2]
\chapter*{Third}
 \lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: can this solution be adapted to -\section* of an article if title is empty (not used)

Comment: @Vaibhav yes, replace "chapter" by "section" everyhere in the code posted.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a short solution:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol,etoolbox}
\newenvironment{Chapter}[2][1]{\chapter[#1]{#2}}{}
%\usepackage{setlistings} private code edited out
\makeatletter
\def\multicols@string{multicols}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{Chapter}{%
  \ifx\@currenvir\multicols@string
     \xdef\resume@multicols{\noexpand\begin{multicols}{\number\col@number}}%
    \end{multicols}%
  \else
    \global\let\resume@multicols\@empty
  \fi}
\AfterEndEnvironment{Chapter}{\resume@multicols}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{Chapter}{Multivariate Algebra I}
\end{Chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{Chapter}{Multivariate Algebra II}
\end{Chapter}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

If you notice the `\Chapter` command has been defined as an environment. This is preferable, as you can then be able to adjust the opening layout for a chapter better. Here for example I use something similar to add the picture layout.

[image][image]

Comment: Your example seems to work without `\usepackage{setlistings}` (which is not part of CTAN). Is this code line redundant?

Comment: @lockstep Yes is not needed. I extracted this from some longer code of mine. I use the same strategy to have the listings full width. I will edit it out. All these between a couple of glasses of wine. Happy New Year and don't edit any tags today:)

Comment: Happy New Year, too. I'll try to restrict myself. ;-)