# Remove page-breaks after chapters in the report class?

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, chapters, report

So I am using the `report` class, and every time I try to create a new `\chapter` it creates it on a new blank page with just the title. I have tried using `\usepackage{etoolbox}` but I keep getting `Latex Error: Float(s) lost` and will not compile. I want to start my chapter on the same page, but I can not figure out how.

Link to full .tex file: http://pastebin.com/Tf55ZmAv

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, twocolumn]{report}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[pdftex,hypertexnames=false,linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\title{TITLE}
\author{RPBruiser}
\date{April 13, 2015}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Stuff is here.
\end{abstract}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\chapter{Introduction}
Context of Chapter 1
\chapter{Methods}
\section{Housing}
Information 123525
-------------HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO BE ON SAME PAGE-------------
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\clearpage}{}
\chapter{results}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a _complete_ example that shows the problem. If I try the following document it all comes on one page, so your page breaks are due to code you have not shown or described, which makes it hard to help. `\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Zzzzzzzzz}
\section{This}
xxxx
\section{That}
yyyyyyy
\end{document}`

Comment: `\chapter` always starts on a new page, but does not force a page break after the title.

Comment: using crystal ball, i guess that you're placing the `\chapter{...}` commands in one file, followed by `\include{filename}`.  if that's what you're doing, you need to place the `\chapter{...}` command *within* the file to be `\include`d, since `\include` by definition starts a new page, as does `\chapter` as already noted by david carlisle..

Comment: @barbarabeeton @david-carlisle I have updated my question to include the actual code. And let me be a tad more specific. I have `\chapter{Methods}` and `\chapter{Results}`, however, these are on two separate pages, a page break before the title of Results chapter. This something I do not want. I want the end of Methods and beginning of Results o be on one page

Comment: Please create a small document which shows the problem - you only need a few lines. Questions here should be self-contained so they remain useful even when the contents of external links changes or disappears. Here's a link to some help with creating a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). I'm not clear right now whether the problem is just that a new chapter starts a new page or if it is that a new chapter starts a new page and all the new page contains is the title of that chapter. Are you using the default chapter format? Or have you customised it?

Comment: @cfr I have now added working code that explains my problem

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Start new chapter on same page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24066/24974)

Comment: @erik No. I think maybe of [this linked question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34689/chapter-without-pagebreak-in-twocolumn-document), though. Notice that the OP is using `twocolumn` and the comments on the original question mention the solution there failing in `twocolumn` mode. But the question linked from there does contain a solution. Perhaps the OP could say whether that question seems to be a duplicate?

Comment: @cfr Thanks, I didn't notice the comment about `twocolumn`.

Comment: @cfr The link you posted is very close to what I wish to do, however, I want the chapter titles to also be two columned, however if it is no possible I can fill gaps with figures. Thank you so much for your help.